# Hypersurfaces of constant phase of light and light cone

Tags: general-relativity, geometric-optics

I am reading Schneider's Gravitational Lenses as textbook. In Chapter 3, it says 'The hypersurfaces of constant phase or wavefronts
are thus everywhere tangent to the local light cone' with Eikonal equation:

\begin{equation}
g^{\alpha \beta} S_{, \alpha} S_{, \beta} = 0
\end{equation}

where S is the phase of the light wave.
How does one draw that conclusion from the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation just says the 4-gradient of the phase is null, e.g. light like, e.g. on the light cone.

For a plane wave in a locally flat region:

$$\psi(x^{\mu})=Ae^{i(k_{\mu}x^{\mu})}\equiv Ae^{iS(x^{\mu})}$$

the phase is:

$$S(x^{\mu})=k_{\mu}x^{\mu}$$

so

$$S_{,\mu}=k_{\mu}$$

Then:

$$k^{\mu}k_{\mu} =\big(\frac{\omega}c\big)^2-||\vec k||^2=0$$

i.e.:

$$\omega=kc$$

Thus, if you pick frame and sit at $\vec x_0$ at time $t_0$, so the phase is:

$$ S_0=S(t_0, \vec x_0)=kx_0-\omega t_0$$

and move forward in time $\delta t$, to keep the phase constant you need to move $\vec{\delta}$ so that:

$$ S_1=S(t_0+\delta t, \vec x_0+\vec{\delta})=
\vec k\cdot (\vec x_0+\vec{\delta})-\omega (t_0+\delta t)
=S_0$$

$$\vec k\cdot\vec{\delta}=\omega t $$

so that:

$$||\delta||=\frac{\omega} k t= ct$$

meaning the points of constant phase move along the light cone in the direction of $\hat k$.